# Efficient JS group-to-category conversion function?

Tags: javascript, function

I've got nine groups:

---

`newFencepost`

`oldBoard`

`bigTree`

`largeRock`

`smallPebble`

`toughBoulder`

`diamondRing`

`emeraldNecklace`

`opalBracelet`

and three categories

`wood` , `stone` & `jewel`

---

Each group belongs to one of the three categories, but the category name is not attached to the group object. So the categories know which groups belong to them, but the groups don't know which categories they belong to.

I need to write a function `groupToCat()` that takes `group` as its first parameter and returns the category associated with it.

---

I could do:

```
if (group == newFencepost || group == oldBoard || group == bigTree ){
    var category = wood;
};
```

But that would be ugly, messy, and mean more work each time I add a new category or group.

---

Being a new programmer, I'd rather start by doing the simple things in the right way. What's a proper way to write this function without having to change it when new content is introduced?

Comment: Does each `category` have a list of `group`s? So can you do something like `if(wood.groups.indexOf(group) !== -1) return wood;`?

Comment: yes, the categories know the groups that belong to them. That information can be attached in any way necessary for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest maintaining a list of `categories`. So you could do something similar to:

```
// Assuming all groups were pushed to categories like :
// wood = wood || {groups: []};
// wood.groups.push(bigTree);
// wood.groups.push(newFencepost);
// etc

function groupToCat(group) {
    for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        var category = categories[i];
        // .indexOf on an array will return
        // the index of the passed in object
        // in the array. If it's -1,
        // that means it's not in the array.
        if(category.groups.indexOf(group) !== -1) {
            return category;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you update this explaining how it works? I'm a little confused by the `indexOf(group) !== -1` part

Comment: Does that help a little bit? I also added a comment about how you would structure your `category` objects.

Comment: I'm studying the `push()` method right now to figure your explanation out

Comment: Ok, so you're pushing the group into a category.groups object, which gives it an index of 0 or greater.. Each loop tries a different category. If the indexOf `group` isn't -1, it's a member of that category. Alright. Makes sense.

Comment: What does this do? `wood = wood || {groups: []};`

Comment: @jt0dd: That says that if wood already exists, we just use that. If it doesn't, we declare it as a new object with a property of `groups` which is an empty array. It's equivalent to `if(wood == null) { wood = {groups:[]}; }`

Comment: I only just got around to implementing this kind of function in a script. Could you clarify how the `categories` object should be created? Is it supposed to be an array?

Comment: Yes, `categories` should be an array of objects.

Comment: Could you take a look at my attempt to utilize this? http://jsfiddle.net/RZ2fQ/ - I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You were close! Just need to move the `categories` definition to below the declaration of the individual categories. I'd also move them out to a separate function (but still have them be global, or at least tied to a global object) so that you don't go through the process of recreating them every time.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that was my issue. Also, I tried another approach as well. Do you recommend yours above the one I created here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491830/js-category-conversion-function?noredirect=1#comment34218400_22491830 ?

Comment: I'd recommend my approach above, as it has one less loop, so is an order of magnitude more efficient. If the second one is easier for you to understand, though, and this won't be called many times with large categories, etc, then that's a fine option as well.